# How to check if any items in listbox match another listbox

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

So, I need to check if any names listed in listbox1 are listed in listbox2 or not.

If there is a name in listbox1 that is NOT in listbox2, then perform an action. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to select all the items in both the List boxes and insert them into their own lists respectively, then you can use the [`Except`](https://www.dotnetperls.com/except) extension method to subtract the elements from the second list from the first list to yield *the names in listbox1 that are NOT in listbox2*.

```
var listBox1 = ListBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
var listBox2 = ListBox2.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();
var resultSet = listBox1.Except(listBox2);

foreach (var item in resultSet)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the selected value in each listbox then pass them to a string variable, then use if and else statements to compare

Example

```
If(a ==b)
{
//do nothing
}
else
{
//do something
}
```

Or you could always try it this way

```
If(a != b)
{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a foreach loop to compare if the item on Listbox1 is not on Listbox2:

```
 foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            if (!listBox2.Items.Contains(item))
            {
               //TODO: Do your logic here   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer:

> check if any names listed in listbox1 are listed in listbox2 or not

```
foreach (var list1Item in listBox1.Items)
    foreach(var list2Item in lisBox2.Items)
        if (list1Item == list2Item)
        {
           // Identical items found. Handle with your code 
        }
```

And to:

> If there is a name in listbox1 that is NOT in listbox2, then perform an action. How to do this?

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
        if(!listBox2.Items.Contains(item))
        {
           // 'item' is present in listBox1, not in listBox2. Handle yourself.
        }
```